# XSL match node on multiple values

Tags: xml, xslt

i have an xml document which looks abit like

```
<a>
<somenode att="1"></somenode>
</a>
<a01>
<apple att="2"></apple>
<somenode att="1"></somenode>
</a01>
```

what im trying to do is match when node name is 'a' or a followed by one number (a0) and a followed by two number (a01), any ideas on how I can do this ?

I have the following so far

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[starts-with(name(),'a')]">
```

but this will select apple aswell, also how to do multiple matches like and OR/AND ?

Comment: Have you looked into the [XPath specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)? Also, why would you expect `apple` *not* to be selected by `starts-with(name(), 'a')`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper c11ada didn't say s/he didn't expect it to select apple. S/he simply said that what s/he has so far (that formula) has that issue.

Comment: @JLRishe: I interpreted "but this will select apple aswell" as "I did not want `apple` to get selected."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I interpreted it differently, but I guess that's a moot point. :)

Comment: c11ada: Could you give an example of what you want to do with "multiple matches like OR/AND"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 this would be pretty simple:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[matches(name(),'^a\d?\d?$')]">
```

In XSLT 1.0, regex isn't available, so it's a little trickier, but the following should work:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[starts-with(name(), 'a') and
                                    string-length(name()) &lt;= 3 and
                                    translate(name(), '0123456789', '') = 'a']" />
```

The three parts joined by "and" here ensure that:

- The name starts with "a"
- The name is 3 characters or less
- All that remains when digits are removed from the name is the string "a" (meaning that any characters besides that single "a" were digits).